# What is the syntax in TextMate to insert a new line '\n' before every capital letter?

Tags: regex, textmate

I'm looking for a way to insert a new line before every capital letter within TextMate

[A-Z] to \n[A-Z]

[image: a-Z result]

Resulted in [A-Z] for every capital letter.

[A-Z] to \n$1

[image]

Resulted in every capital letter being removed.

What is the syntax in TextMate to insert a new line '\n' before every capital letter?

Comment: `([A-Z])` to `\n$1`

Comment: Try a capturing group `([A-Z])` and replace with `\n$1`

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate because of a different search term seems strange to me. The first time I've ever seen the term 'backreference' is today ... after asking this question.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew `([A-Z]) to \n$1` worked.